# How can I determine the original dataset of an observation after rbind?

Tags: r, dataset

I have 113 different datasets and use the R-command "rbind" to put them into one single dataset.
Now my question: How can I determine from which original dataset a specific observation stems? Is there any command in R for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable called for example "origin" in each of the $i=113$ datasets and set it equal to the dataset number $i$ for each dataset before you merge them using rbind

Here is a one line to illustrate ...

```
rbind(data.frame(x=rnorm(10),origin=1),data.frame(x=rnorm(10),origin=2))
5  -0.03722076      1
6  -0.27234819      1
7   0.16789858      1
8  -0.36891022      1
9  -0.75885937      1
10  0.44140187      1
11 -0.47577163      2
12 -0.70214144      2
13 -0.43769029      2
```

And in the future: Questions solely about R should not be asked here but for example on Stack Overflow.